# Firebase functions return error text from external API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, square-connect

I am using Firebase functions to process credit cards through square. My function works great for successful card transactions.  However, with card errors such as declined or incorrect cvv, I want to send that error context to the user.  What happens with my current code I just get an error 500 from the cloud function.  When I look at the function logs, it has an Unhandled error { Error: Bad Request...  I can see the desired text in the log but this doesn't get passed to the front end.  Here is my current code.

```
export const processPayment = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  squareSetup();
  const request_params = data;
  const idempotency_key = crypto.randomBytes(22).toString('hex');
  const payments_api = new squareConnect.PaymentsApi();
  const request_body = {
    source_id: request_params.nonce,
    amount_money: {
      amount: Math.round(request_params.amount * 100),
      currency: 'USD' as squareConnect.CurrencyType
    },
    tip_money: {
      amount: Math.round(request_params.tipAmount * 100),
      currency: 'USD' as squareConnect.CurrencyType
    },
    idempotency_key: idempotency_key
  };
  return payments_api.createPayment(request_body);
});
```

According to the api found [here](https://github.com/square/connect-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/docs/CreatePaymentResponse.md).  I should get a response of an array of Error types.  However when I use a catch on the api promise like this

```
return payments_api.createPayment(request_body).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

It is not that.  Instead it seems to be a full error response

```
{ Error: Bad Request
at Request.callback (/srv/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:706:15)
at parser (/srv/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:18)
at IncomingMessage.res.on (/srv/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:19:7)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  status: 400,
  response: 
   Response {
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [Array] },
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     res: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 400,
        statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Object],
        text: '{"errors": [{"code": "CVV_FAILURE","detail": "Authorization error: \'CVV_FAILURE\'","category": "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"}],"payment": {"id": "xq1y6ue6tKTZhAdbWJUwf5WHsobZY","created_at": "2020-05-19T22:45:36.408Z","updated_at": "2020-05-19T22:45:36.516Z","amount_money": {"amount": 2030,"currency": "USD"},"tip_money": {"amount": 0,"currency": "USD"},"status": "FAILED","delay_duration": "PT168H","source_type": "CARD","card_details": {"status": "FAILED","card": {"card_brand": "VISA","last_4": "1111","exp_month": 12,"exp_year": 2021,"fingerprint": "sq-1-jEohVzE5NqHD6_pF2AVfTSFbT1rRlEpA-FxCHw3ZEx1w3VgafAXvemqYf_AyJN7Dyg","card_type": "CREDIT","bin": "411111"},"entry_method": "KEYED","cvv_status": "CVV_REJECTED","avs_status": "AVS_ACCEPTED","errors": [{"code": "CVV_FAILURE","detail": "Authorization error: \'CVV_FAILURE\'","category": "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"}]},"location_id": "NQYE9M4YWEVJ9","order_id": "grj0Ni4UoMVWdjhUG7NbRSWibb4F","total_money": {"amount": 2030,"currency": "USD"},"delay_action": "CANCEL","delayed_until": "2020-05-26T22:45:36.408Z"}}\n',
        read: [Function] },
     request: 
      Request {
        domain: [Object],
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _agent: false,
        _formData: null,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://connect.squareupsandbox.com/v2/payments',
        _header: [Object],
        header: [Object],
        writable: true,
        _redirects: 0,
        _maxRedirects: 5,
        cookies: '',
        qs: {},
        _query: [],
        qsRaw: [],
        _redirectList: [],
        _streamRequest: false,
        _timeout: 60000,
        _responseTimeout: 0,
        _data: [Object],
        req: [Object],
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'connect.squareupsandbox.com',
        _endCalled: true,
        _callback: [Function],
        res: [Object],
        response: [Circular],
        called: true },
     req: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 203,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /v2/payments HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: connect.squareupsandbox.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Square-Connect-Javascript/3.20200422.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer EAAAEP4ScCd1MuybJhfZaTDovR_0KG06LwxrKdREpSnKhNUZ2_3T0kH0AcUycdgI\r\nSquare-Version: 2020-04-22\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 203\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v2/payments',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Object],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
```

I can see the expected error response from the api under a property called text but I am unsure how to drill down to just that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the expected response by simply drilling down with

```
return payments_api.createPayment(request_body).catch((err) => console.log(err.response.text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the error, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors):

> To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
>   callable **by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an
>   instance of** `functions.https.HttpsError`.

So, in your case, you should do something like the following (I make the assumption that the `createPayment()` method returns a Promise):

```
export const processPayment = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  //...
  return payments_api.createPayment(request_body)
  .catch(error => {
     throw new functions.https.HttpsError('<error-code>', '....');
  })
});
```

The list of possible error codes is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode).

---

You will find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client), some examples on how to handle the error in the client side.

Comment: Okay so I can throw an error but how do I get the text from the original error returned from the external server?

Comment: Can you point me to the square API documentation? You should get the error of the API in the catch.

Comment: Sure the specific response in the documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/square/connect-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/docs/CreatePaymentResponse.md).  The problem is that the error returned in the catch is not just that response.  It is wrapped in the entire { Error: Bad Request.... with status: 400, response: etc.  I can see the error response from the documentation listed under a property call text.  I was wondering how I drill down to just that.

Comment: From what I can see you  receive an array of errors and each error has a `detail` property. So you could use a `forEach` to loop over the `error` objects and build a message to be sent back to the users.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I expected the error to be but instead it seems to be something else.  I have updated my original question with more detail about what I am getting